# Pass parameters to jquery function on onclick

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onclick

I am trying to pass a parameter to my jquery function through the onclick event of a textbox. This is the code:

HTML Code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginName" OnClick='timepass(<%# Eval("userid")%>);' Text='<%# Eval("LoginName")%>'
                                runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and my jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function timepass(pass) {
            alert(pass);
}
```

but nothing happens. When I pass like this on onclick event `OnClick="timepass(123)"` it works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: may be because `LoginName` is a string value so try `OnClick='timepass("<%# Eval("LoginName")%>");'`

Comment: yes it is a string value...but still nothing happens when I try your way

Comment: may be something to do with teh asp syntax... never used it

Comment: yeah i think its something with the placement of ' or " but i tried some combinations it gives "server tag not well formed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the value like:

```
onclick='<%# "timepass(" + Eval("LoginName") + ");" %>'

<script type="text/javascript">
        function timepass(pass) {
           alert(pass);
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry i forgot to mention that both the values are not same. I have updated my question

Comment: Hi...your solution works perfectly after changing onclientclick to onclick. Please update your answer so that I can mark it